# DataTable Compute Rows returned based on Month from a DateTime Column

Tags: c#, datetime, datatables

I am trying to get row count returned from one of my DataTables. Usually it is easy and I have done it many times. But this unique case is troubling me. I need to return the row counts based on a DateTime column but based on a month as its filter. This is what I currently have which is failing.

```
sickLCount = Convert.ToInt32(LeaveDays.Compute("COUNT(EmployeeID)", "LeaveType = 0 AND month(Date) = "+ startDate.Value.Month + ""));
```

Besides this I also tried the LINQ approach - unfortunately it is not returning me any result. Below is the LINQ i tried.

```
sickLCount = LeaveDays.AsEnumerable()
            .Where(r => r.Field<DateTime>("Date").Month == startDate.Value.Month).Count();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the main problem is to use a function called `month()` in your datatable.

If your data would in your database, you could call `month()` function easily. But your data is *not* in your database anymore, it is in your datatable right now. You *can't* run database query functions in your datatable.

My suggestion is, get the month part of your as a different column - lets say `Months` - and filter *that* column with your `startDate.Value.Month` value.

The "filter" on `Compute` method follows [`DataColumn.Expression` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression) rules by the way. You might wanna check it out for more details.

Comment: I was thinking of something like that now :) - Let me check it up and update u about my result

Answer (score 0):

Replace `.Field("Date")` with `.Field<DateTime>("Date")`

Also you can consolidate by using Count instead of Where:

```
LeaveDays.AsEnumerable().Count(r => r.Field<DateTime>("Date").Month == startDate.Value.Month);
```